# How to declare stream output in GS in HLSL?

Tags: glsl, hlsl, directx-9

I want to implement Stream output stage in DX9 using HLSL. Stream output buffers are passed in Geometry shaders. How to implements this Stream output logic in GS when writing in HLSL?

Answer (score 0):

DX9 doesn't support Geometry Shaders or Stream Output.